# How to get different UID using Dynamic Users with socket activation?

Tags: systemd, socket-activation

I'm following the [Dynamic Users with systemd](https://0pointer.net/blog/dynamic-users-with-systemd.html) post and creating the `waldo.socket` and `waldo.service`.

Here is my `waldo.socket`.

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=2048
Accept=yes
```

And the corresponding `waldo@.service`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=-sleep 300
DynamicUser=yes
```

It works nicely, but I discovered that all `sleep 300` are launched with the same UID.

```
$ ps fax -o uid,pid,cmd | grep sleep
61647   87279 sleep 300
61647   87282 sleep 300
61647   87285 sleep 300
```

I'd like to have each instance of the service using a distinct UID, as is implied in that article

> By combining dynamic user IDs with socket activation you may easily implement a system where each incoming connection is served by a process instance running as a different, fresh, newly allocated UID within its own sandbox.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: May be try making it not a template service. i.e rename it to `waldo.service`?

Comment: Then all connections are served by the same service, which is precisely what I do *not* want